# If-elif statement: condition based on two existing files

Tags: bash, if-statement

I have a set of three files in around 90 sub-directories. I'm trying to run a for loop to execute a command based on the presence/absence of specific set of files. This has multiple conditions, here is an example-

```
for subj in `cat sublist.txt`; do 
if [ -a ${subj}/${subj}*file1 && -a ${subj}/${subj}*file2 ]; then
blah blah...
elif [ -a ${subj}/${subj}*file1 && -a ${subj}/${subj}*file3 ]; then
blah blah...
elif [ -a ${subj}/${subj}*file2 && -a ${subj}/${subj}*file3 ]; then
balh blah...
elif [ -a ${subj}/${subj}*file1 ! -a ${subj}/${subj}*file2 && ! -a ${subj}/${subj}*file3 ]; then
blah blah...
elif [ -a ${subj}/${subj}*file2 ! -a ${subj}/${subj}*file1 && ! -a ${subj}/${subj}*file3 ]; then
blah blah
else blah blah
fi 
done
```

I'm constantly getting syntax error- bash: [: missing `]'

I have attempted to run this with -[[ ]] and have checked for errors in spaces.
What can be wrong with my script? How can I correct to be able provide correct input file for my command?

Thank you in advance for the feedback/suggestion

Comment: Always first test your script to https://shellcheck.net before asking here.

Comment: why don't you try `if [ -a ${subj}/${subj}*file1 ] && [ -a ${subj}/${subj}*file2 ]...`
etc.

Comment: Hi. `[ -a ${subj}/${subj}*file1 && -a ${subj}/${subj}*file2 ]` Please explain what is this supposed to mean? It doesn't compile in my head - `-a` means "and", how can you "and" `[` and many files from glob? Are you checking the presence or absence of which files exactly? What is `-a` supposed to do? Why are you using `*`? Do you want to check the existence of a specifically named file, or you want to check if a glob `*` matches at least 1 file?

Comment: @KamilCuk _Unary_ `-a` is deprecated but still is valid in the code. The error is using `&&` within square brackets.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using `bash`'s test with double square bracket:

```
path1=$(compgen -G ${subj}/${subj}*file1) path2=$(compgen -G ${subj}/${subj}*file2)
if [[ -e $path1 && -e $path2 ]]; then
    ...
```

---

`[` or `test` is the `POSIX` test command. It can do simple tests on files and strings. In `bash`, you should use the more powerful `[[` instead and ban `[` for sake of consistency. `[[` can do pattern matching, is faster and safer to use.

See
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals

---

`compgen -G glob*` is a trick to expand [glob](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob)s. You **can't** use wildcards in a test like this.